# Fixed-width integers in C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, types, portability

Occasionally I need to use fixed-width integers for communication with external devices like PLCs. I also use them to define bitmasks and perform bit manipulation of image data. AFAIK the C99 standard defines fixed-width integers like int16_t. However the compiler I use, VC++ 2008 doesn't support C99 and AFAIK Microsoft is not planning to support it.

My question is what is the best practice for using fixed-width integers in C++?

I know that VC++ defines non-standard fixed-width integers like __int16, but I am hesitant to use a non-standard type. Will the next C++ standard define fixed-width integers?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Boost has the typedefs for all of the C99 types and more:
["Boost integer library"](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/integer/index.html)

Comment: Update for actual readers : C++11 now have fixed size types : http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer

Answer (score 19):

You can workaround the problem with some `#ifdef` directives.

```
#ifdef _MSC_VER
   typedef __int16 int16_t
#else
   #include <stdint.h>
#endif
```

Comment: Just FYI for future readers, MSVC 2010 does have `<cstdint>`!

Answer (score 7):

Include the file `<stdint.h>` to get the definitions for types like `uint16_t`.  VC++ doesn't come with `<stdint.h>` by default, but you can get that file from several places.  [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdint.h#Downloads) lists a few, and Google will find you lots more.

Comment: The problem is that stdint.h, like most or all C and C++ headers, is implementation-specific.  The definitions depend on the implementation.  Any random header might work just fine, or fail.

Comment: @David: That's a good point, but in this case the stdint.h files listed on the Wikipedia page are in fact specifically written for MSVC++.

Comment: Ah, so we aren't talking about random headers here.  Good.

Answer (score 4):

> Will the next C++ standard define fixed-width integers?

Yes: [C++11 has fixed-width integers](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/integer).

As Mehrdad said, you can use `#ifdefs` for now. An alternative would be some elaborate template magic. Boost has got something in this direction, the [Boost Integer library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_38_0/libs/integer/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

I've used a public domain (not GPL - true public domain) version of `stdint.h` by Danny Smith that's available in the mingw package:

- http://www.mingw.org/download.shtml

I had to tweak that version to compile with some non VC 8 compilers (mostly VC6) - it has served me well.

Maybe one of these days I'll get around to posting my VC6-compatible version somewhere.  The changes were pretty minor - just some macro trickery to use VC6 specific keywords for 64-bit types.  If you don't need VC6 support, the mingw version should probably be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

There are different paths to take.  Most environments would hold that `short int`s are 16 bits, and `long int`s are 32.  (The `long` is implied when you declare simply `int`.)  If you `typedef` your own int16 type, you'll probably end up using a `short int`.

Another possibility lies with bit fields in structs.  You can say something like:

```
struct x {
    int a : 16;
    int b : 5;
    ...
};
```

And so forth.  If you then define:

```
struct x myvar;
myvar.a = 54;
```

You can be sure that myvar.a will hold 16 bits, and myvar.b will use 5; the total size of myvar rounding up for what all the bits comprise, plus of course the size of any other fields.

Comment: short is usually 16 bits, but long can be either 32 or 64 bits on modern systems.  long long will almost always be 64.

Comment: David's right. If you go this route, I'd at least include something like "assert(sizeof (short) == 2)" somewhere in your code.

Comment: Longs in theory can be 64 bits.  I've never worked with a 64 bit machine, but my impression has been most compilers still keep long at 32 and force you to use long long for 64.  The tricky thing is, I think, this is all implementation-defined regardless of conventions.